# Get incremental changes for users using Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, delta

I was going through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-users?tabs=http

What does this mean:

```
When the user is deleted, the item contains an annotation: @removed with value of "reason": "changed".
When the user is permanently deleted, the item contains an annotation: @removed with value of "reason": "deleted".
```

How do these two differ? Both means user will be removed from the tenant?

Let's say  User 1 & User 2 are a part of Group 1

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName,givenName,surname)",
  "@odata.nextLink":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$skiptoken=oEBwdSP6uehIAxQOWq_3Ksh_TLol6KIm3stvdc6hGhZRi1hQ7Spe__dpvm3U4zReE4CYXC2zOtaKdi7KHlUtC2CbRiBIUwOxPKLa",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "<User 1>",
      "@removed": {
        "reason": "deleted"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "<User 2>",
      "@removed": {
        "reason": "changed"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Does that mean user 1 & user 2 are deleted from tenant + deleted from Group 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of deletion in Azure (Entra, Graph):

- [soft delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
- [permanent delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

When a user is soft deleted, it's moved to a temporary container and can be restored within 30 days. In that case delta for users returns @removed with reason `changed`.

Deleted users can be retrieved through `GET /directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user` [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

After 30 days, user is permanently deleted. User can be permanently deleted sooner when permanent delete is performed manually either by admin or by calling [permanent delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). In that case delta for users returns @removed with reason `deleted`.

Comment: Thank you! If I need to get all the deleted users in the past 7 days for example, can I get that data?

Answer (score 1):

> When the user is deleted, the item contains an annotation: @removed with value of "reason": "changed".

The **'changed'** annotation in the delta query indicates that the user object has been removed from a group, while the user account still exists in the `Azure AD` directory. When a user is `removed from a group`,the delta query will return an item with the **'@removed'** annotation and a 'reason' value of `'changed.'` The user's account is moved to a temporary **'deleted users'** container for a retention period, during which it can be **restored**.

> When the user is permanently deleted, the item contains an annotation: @removed with value of "reason": "deleted".

The **'deleted'** annotation in the delta query indicates that the user account has been permanently removed from the `Azure AD` directory. If a user account is permanently deleted from the `Azure AD` directory, the delta query will return an item with the '@removed' annotation and a 'reason' value of **'deleted.'** The user is **permanently** deleted from the tenant and **cannot be restored**.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=displayName,givenName,surname
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Does that mean user 1 & user 2 are deleted from tenant + deleted from Group 1?

**User 1** has been permanently deleted from the tenant, while **User 2** has been removed from the group but their account still exists in the tenant. It is important to note that the delta query only returns information about users and their **'@removed'** status; it does not necessarily indicate whether **User 1** and **User 2** were both members of Group 1.

[image]

Reference: [Initial response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-users?tabs=http#initial-response)

[Restore or remove a recently deleted user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/users-restore)

Comment: Please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77876689/users-deleted-from-tenant-not-in-delta-api-response